# How do I get a hold of the authData when removing a user in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

When removing data in Firebase I've previous used:

```
MyFirebaseRef.on('child_removed', function (oldChildSnapshot) {
     /* oldChildSnapshot => the data that's been erased */
});
```

But now I would like to do the same thing when removing a user i.e. getting hold of the data that's related to the user, mainly the UID, so I've done like this:

```
MyFirebaseRef.removeUser({
  email: "EMAIL",
  password: "PASSWORD"
}, function (error, authData) {
    if (error === null) {
        console.log("User removed successfully", authData.uid);
    } else {
        console.log("Error removing user:", error);
    }
  }
});
```

But `authData` is `undefined` so there is no way of getting hold of the UID. Is there any way of achieving this ?

Answer (score 1):

The `authData` parameter isn't passed back in the [`removeUser` method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html#section-deleting).

However, if you store your user's data in Firebase you should be able to get the `uid` by an email address.

```
{
  "users": {
    "a8562a24-3a56-4b60-b9f3-00042908fd0e": {
      "name": "KJ",
      "email": "kjisawesome@kj.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can do a query to get back the user by email address.

```
var kjsEmail = 'kjisawesome@kj.com';
var ref = new Firebase('<my-firebase-app>.firebaseio.com/users');
ref.orderByChild('email').equalTo(kjsEmail).once(function(snap) {
  console.log(snap.val()); // user data
  console.log(snap.key()); // uid
});
```

Comment: My problem is that I have `"users": { "a8562a24-3a56-4b60-b9f3-00042908fd0e": "AES Encryption" }`. So I'm only able to relate to the UID never able to access the data under it without the AES Encryption key only  known to the specific user.

Comment: If an admin is doing deletes, shouldn't the admin have access to the key as well?

Comment: The thing is that the admins in my case could change and the specific user should later on be able to add themselves so I've chosen the method with the thought that no one but the user can check their data. The admin would only be able to delete the user.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you should do in your situation as most Firebase users don't use AES encryption due to the it's serverless nature. Why do you need the deleted uid?

Comment: I have within my Firebase users which I add with the `Firebase.createUser()` when creating a user this way I also create user data with `Firebase.push()/.set()`. So I have `User(Email,Pword) <-|UID|-> User Data(Real name, Company, etc..)`. So my connection is only the UID and when removing a user with `Firebase.removeUser()` I'm trying to get a hold of the UID so I'm also able to delete the `User Data(Real name, Company, etc..)`

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to handle your situation since you're using AES encryption, but you might be able to create a lookup node which as the email address as the key (escaped for the @) mapped to the UID.